# RedirectingtoAction not working in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am trying to redirect my page to this url http://somedomain.com/Admin/#/Admin/Partial1, I wrote this code in the controller. But redirecting to this url http://somedomain.com/Admin/%23/Admin/Partial1 and page was not landing. If I remove %23 from the generated url then the page was landing perfectly.

Please help me someone how to solve this problem.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Partial1(string Email)
    {
        //some thing code..
        return RedirectToAction("/#/Admin/Partial1");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the #?

Comment: You cannot do that. RedirectToAction takes an action name as a string.  and you cannot have an action like "/#/Admin/Partial1". Please try to explain what you are trying to achieve. it look like you want a partial rendered

Comment: @Amila Representing **%23** into the url when i use 'RedirectToAction("/#/Admin/Partial1")' method. is there any alterate way to avoid **%23**

Comment: what is the purpose of `/#/Admin/Partial1` in your url?

Comment: @Amila for internal JQuery plug-in i should use # in the url.